# data should replace the old data in the table after every 5 sec but its adding every time jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm working with Data Tables and trying to refresh the incoming data every few seconds without refreshing the page. Initial page load works but after the set delay I get an error "Datatables warning(table id = 'example'): cannot reinitialise data table". Looked at the data table website for help but couldn't find anything specific to my setup. Any feedback appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:30px">
        <h2 class="col-xs-12">
            Cryptocurrency Market Capitalizations
        </h2>
        <h5>$USD</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding:0">
            <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered hover" style="margin:0 auto">
                <thead id="tableHeader">
                    <tr>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Market Cap</td>
                        <td>Available Supply</td>
                        <td>24 HR % Change</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="mainTable">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;margin-top:50px">
            <img src="imgs/loading.gif" style="height:120px" id="loading">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is javascript

```
function executeQuery() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://coincap.io/front",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var items = [];
            var len = data.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var numFormat = data[i].price.toLocaleString("en");
                var numFormat1 = data[i].mktcap.toLocaleString("en");
                var numFormat2 = data[i].supply.toLocaleString("en");
                var lowerCaseName = data[i].long.toLowerCase();
                items.push("<tr><td>" + [i+1] + "</td><td> <span class='sprite sprite-" + lowerCaseName + " small_coin_logo'></span>" + data[i].long + " - " + data[i].short + "</td><td> $" + numFormat + "</td><td> $" + numFormat1 + "</td><td>" + numFormat2 + "</td><td class='marketChange'>" + data[i].cap24hrChange + "% </td></tr>");
            }
            $(".mainTable").append(items.join(""));
        },
        complete: function() {            }
    });
    setTimeout(executeQuery, 5000);
}
$(document).ready(function() { $("#loading").addClass("hide");
            $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                "lengthMenu": [ 20, 50, 75, 100 ],
                "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
                language: { search: "" }
            });
            $('#dataTable_filter input[type="search"]').attr('placeholder', 'Search for coins');
            $('#dataTable_filter input[type="search"]').css("padding-left","9px");
    setTimeout(executeQuery, 5000);
});
setInterval(function() {  $('#dataTable')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);}, 1500);
```

Comment: have you tried `$('#DataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();`?

Comment: If you're appending straight like that, you could maybe `$('.mainTable').empty();` before appending new data?

Answer (score 0):

use `.DataTable().ajax.reload();`

change

```
setInterval(function() {  $('#dataTable')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);}, 1500);
```

to

```
setInterval(function() {  $('#DataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();}, 1500);
```

Simple example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/ju2bmtm7/224/)

Your example: [jsfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/ov7wf1rj/11/)